# A Compact Hausdorff Space with no Manifold Structure?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, examples-counterexamples, smooth-manifolds

What is an example of a compact Hausdorff space that cannot be given the structure of a

(i)   differential manifold

(ii)  topological manifold?

Comment: Please specify if you include manifolds with boundary. If not, $[0,1]$ is the most basic example.

Comment: Also, is connectedness required? If not, $\{0,1\}$ will do. I suppose you should state your definitions of these objects, since there are several in common use.

Comment: @MPW Your example is still a compact Hausdorff 0-manifold, isn't it?

Comment: @JoeyBF: Yes, I should have said "if so" rather than "if not". My bad. The point is that it violates the connectivity requirement.

Comment: For us to be certain. I am looking for the manifolds that are without boundary and that are connected. So $[0,1]$ is a very good example.

Comment: I see no sense in closing this question. There are already several good answers, with many upvotes, one of which is accepted, and there are good discussions in the comments of the answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The union of the $x$-axis and $y$-axis in $\mathbb{R}^2$, intersected with the closed unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

[image]

Comment: Is this compact?

Comment: Hi @Abo, sorry yes, it wasn't compact as I initially stated, but that condition can be satisfied with a slight modification.

Comment: A fan or comb captures this idea

Comment: Perhaps a more intuitive description of this space is to say _the union of two line segments sharing a non-end-point_.

Comment: Hi @leftaroundabout, yes, or simply a "plus sign"/"cross". I've added an image to hopefully illustrate the point, although it's a bit thicker than I would like ...

Comment: @AmiteshDatta: You might as well post "{\Huge +}" in LaTeX.

Answer (score 9):

The Cantor set is a nice example.

Comment: For some strange values of "nice"...

Comment: For example, "nice" $=$ "looks locally the same at every point", as a manifold does. @ZhenLin

Comment: I'd really add that comment to your answer -- in a way it's a more insidious counterexample than the cross.

Answer (score 4):

The cartesian product $[0,1]^{\Bbb R}$ is obviously compact and Hausdroff, but isn't locally homeomorphic to any $\Bbb R^n$. The really interesting (and hard) case is a [topological manifold without differentiable structure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58061/how-can-there-be-topological-4-manifolds-with-no-differentiable-structure).

Comment: Why $[0,1]^{\mathbb{R}}$? Actually $[0,1]^I$ for every non-empty set $I$ works. And if we are only interested in examples, $\#I=1$ suffices.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, true. But the case of manifolds vith borders/corners was already mentioned by... you.

Answer (score 3):

The interval $[0,1]$ is a compact Hausdorff space which doesn't carry the structure of a manifold without boundary. (Of course, it carries the structure of a manifold with boundary.)

Answer (score 2):

Any set that has an accumulation point and an isolated point

Comment: You mean subspace of $\mathbb{R}$? There is no notion of an isolated/accumulation point for a *set*.

Comment: What? Of course I intend for this set to be endowed with a topology.  Specifically, "Any compact Hausdorff space that has an isolated point and an accumulation point".

Comment: So why are you writing "set"?

Comment: Enough of this. That the set carries a compact Hausdorff topology is implicit in the terminology I used and the context of the question.